# Define attributes for media list and return values in one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to build a media list which can hold different media types like movies, tv series, books, games and each of those types can have different attributes attached to them.

Right now I have the following tables:

```
categories

catid   | name
1       | Books
2       | Movies
3       | Tv Series

media

mid     | title         | catid
1       | Book 1        | 1
2       | Movie 1       | 2
3       | TV Series 1   | 3
4       | Book 2        | 1
5       | Movie 2       | 2

attributes

attrid  | catid | name
1       | 1     | number of pages
2       | 1     | description
3       | 1     | year
4       | 2     | length
5       | 2     | cast
6       | 2     | description
7       | 3     | cast
8       | 3     | description
9       | 3     | year
10      | 3     | number of episodes

attribute_info

attraid | mid   | attrid    | value
1       | 1     | 1         | 213
2       | 1     | 2         | Description...
3       | 1     | 3         | 1996
4       | 2     | 4         | 210 minutes 
5       | 2     | 5         | Actor1, Actor2
6       | 2     | 6         | Description...
7       | 3     | 7         | Actor3, Actor4
8       | 3     | 8         | Description...
9       | 3     | 9         | 2010
10      | 3     | 10        | 12
```

`categories` holds information about the different media types. `media` holds information about the individual media entry, `attributes` defines the different attibutes per category and `attribute_info` finally holds the info itself.

Now I'm looking for an efficient way to fetch the information via `SQL`
Ideally I could group all information a media property has into one output row and get something like

```
Array([mid] => 1, [title] => Book 1, [catid] => 1, [name] => Books, [number of pages] => 213, [description] => Description..., [year] => 1996)
```

Ways to do this should be inner joins but I don't like to change my PHP code when I add an attribute to a category. What's an elegant in `SQL` way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to make two queries, one to get category and title, and then another to get all the attribute-attribute_info pairs for that mid. Then, append the second array to the first one.

Of course, you're going to run into problems there if any of your attributes match one of your titles. :)